# R: calculating the probability of an outcome following Gumbel distribution

Tags: r, distribution

I have an equation of the form

> P[x>y]

where x, y follows a Gumbel (type 1) distribution. I have been given x, y and need to calculate the probability. I found these two functions after searches:

1. `pgumbel` in package `gumbel` but that is for Gumbel Coupla with parameters alpha
2. `pgumbelII` in package `VGAM`, but that is for Gumbel II

Any directions would be appreciated.

(I am a novice and just starting out in R. I couldn't find the answer online - but if this is a repeat question, feel free to steer me to a proper solution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about function from [Extreme Value Distributions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/evd/evd.pdf) package?

```
library(evd)

q <- 1
pgumbel(q)
```

Of course, if you don't have evd, run

```
install.packages("evd")
```

Windows 10 x64, Microsoft R Open r3.5.3